# Short way to turn a known-length array into separate variables

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this chunk of code:

```
var input = aString.split(' ').map(Number);
var a = input[0];
var b = input[1];
var c = input[2];
var d = input[3];
```

I know that the string will always have four space-separated entries, so input will always be an array of length 4. I will always put those 4 entries into separated variables.

The context is a code golf. I have made the code more readable for the sake of the question, but I can't use inputs[k] every time I need it later (it's longer than a single-character variable). I am hoping to turn it into four variables easily. For example, if it was valid javascript, the following code would be perfect:

```
var input = aString.split(' ').map(Number);
var a, b, c, d = input[0:3];
```

I am looking for some way to reduce as much as possible the size of the section of the code that turns input into a certain number of variables. Any improvement is useful because in the real case, there are a 12 variables instead of 4 (but it will never change). That's a big improvement if I can reduce the number of chars this way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Array_destructuring):

```
var [a, b, c, d] = aString.split(' ').map(Number);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. It is very hard to google something when you have no idea what it's called. Thank you kind stranger! I will accept this answer as soon as SO lets me